# Special Characters in php - SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, encode

I'm new in using PHP on Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server. When I want to post (or with the get method) some variables and I want to store them in the database, it converts characters like a space -> `%20`, and `é` -> `%C3`, but I don't want the system to store `%20` or `%C3` but the actual character `é`. How can I do this? The page has encoding **utf-8** and the collation is **Latin1_General_100_CS_AS**

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the wind, but when you perform a get the form data is being encoded into a URL and you'll get this behavior. Using the post method shouldn't necessarily encode the form values for spaces but for the special characters. Here is a good refernence to look at, http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Try `urldecode`.

It will take the url-safe representations and convert them to actual characters.  See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

NOTE the warning in the manual, that you do not have to do this with GET or POST variables. They are automatically decoded.

```
$my_var = $_GET['my_weird_character'];
```

$my_var should already be decoded and ready for you do enter into your DB. Have you tried it yet? Before worrying and asking questions like this, why not try it and see if it works first?